# Determining the value of an object

Tags: c#-3.0

I have an object which can have value as

3334.0 or

3

I need to check if it is having .0 or not. how can it be done?

If I do a string conevrsion i.e. object.tostring() or Convert.toString(object), then for the value 3334.0 it will be 3334.

Hence I cannot do so.

Basically I need to find if the value in the object is a decimal or not?

Help needed

Thanks

Comment: Why in the world are you using the `object` type, instead of a more specific type for your variable? Since you're using C# 3.0, you could also use generics. Either would be better than the constant boxing to and from an `object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would looking at it's type help?

```
    Object a = 1;   // int
    Object b = 2f;  // float
    Object c = 3m;  // decimal

    Response.Write(a.GetType() + ", " + b.GetType() + ", " + c.GetType());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is fairly ambiguous.  What kind of object is it?
If you have an object reference, and the *type* can be different, then you can check it using this:

```
object obj = GetSomeObject();
if(obj is decimal)
{
    Console.WriteLine("It is a decimal");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("It isn't a decimal, it's a: " + obj.GetType());
}
```